# Failed to create JDBC connection for DB2 in powerdesigner

Tags: jdbc, db2, powerdesigner

I've no idea why get the msg when test the jdbc connection

SQLSTATE = UNKNOWN
DatabaseMetaData information is not known for server DB2/LINUXZ64SQL10013 by this version of JDBC driver

[image]

Comment: Are you able to connect with other tools?  Is this just a problem with PowerDesigner (perhaps it doesn't know about or support DB2 10.1 on z/Linux)?

Answer (score 1):

If you are connecting to a DB2 LUW you do not need the db2jcc_license_cu.jar file, just the db2jcc.jar or db2jcc4.jar.

Also, make sure you can connect to the server (telnet c03z0040.pok.dst.ibm.com 60044)

Once you are sure you can connect, you test the db2 driver:

```
java com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Jcc -url jdbc:db2://c03z0040.pok.dst.ibm.com:60044/bhc -user stellalw -password XXXX
```